# ¿Por qué el antónimo de "indeciso" es "decidido" en lugar de "deciso"?

Tags: etimología, historia, antónimos

El prefijo "[in](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Prefijo)"  puede denotar negación o privación de algo. Ejemplo:

- Capaz - **in**capaz
- Imaginable - **in**imaginable
- Alcanzable - **in**alcanzable

La construcción de estos ejemplos parece seguir un patrón bastante regular. En estos días necesité el antónimo de "indeciso" y no me vino a la mente de inmediato. Luego vi que era "decidido", pero me surgió la duda de por qué el antónimo no era simplemente "decido", siguiendo el patrón que se ve en otras palabras.

Mirando la palabra indeciso en el DLE:

> [**indeciso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LM0Gq2Y)
>
> De *in*<sup>2</sup> y el lat. *decīsus* 'decidido'.
>
> **1**. *adj*. Dicho de una cosa: Sobre la cual no ha caído resolución.
>
> **2**. *adj*. Perplejo, irresoluto, que tiene dificultad para decidirse.

En el origen de la palabra se menciona *decisus* en latin como precursora de "decidido".

Así que, colocando con otro enfoque la pregunta en el título, ¿por qué evolucionó *decisus* a "decidido" pero se conservó su forma original para formar el antónimo "indeciso"?

Comment: No creo que los prefijos posean reglas en particular. Considerando *honesto* lo hace diferente; *posible* u *obediente*. Yo creo que se basa netamente en la derivación del latín.

Comment: @Ustanak de acuerdo, pero en este caso en particular el "in" si da la idea de negación o privación. Mi duda está en la raíz: ¿por qué el cambio de "decisus" a "decidido"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Decidido* no proviene de *decīsus*, sino que es el participio regular de *decidir* derivado según las reglas actuales. La forma regular desplazó a la irregular como ocurrió en muchos otros verbos latinos.

En cuanto a *indeciso*, es un adjetivo, no una forma verbal. No sé si hay muchos verbos primitivos que incorporen *in-* como negación (*imposibilitar* es una forma derivada). La falta de acción se traduce naturalmente con cópula + adjetivo, no como verbo activo. No es raro que *indeciso* haya evolucionado por su cuenta, especialmente si ya existía como palabra reconocida antes.

En castellano tenemos todavía *recluir* y *prender* con participios regularizados por analogía, *recluido* y *prendido*, y los antiguos participios irregulares (del mismo patrón que el de *decidir*) transformados en sustantivos, *recluso* y *preso* (este último también adjetivo). Estos términos tienen un uso bastante específico y una semántica clara: son pacientes (*recluso* = quien está o fue recluido; *preso* = quien fue prendido por la policía).

No sé qué podría significar **deciso* si existiese, pero claramente no sería un paciente.

En castellano medieval existía *defeso* como participio de *defender*. Hoy en día empleamos *defendido* como participio y también para designar al que está siendo defendido en un juicio (por lo menos lo usan así los abogados cuando dicen "mi defendido"). Éste es claramente un paciente de acción y sin embargo la existencia con otros similares no bastó para preservar *defeso*.

Comment: Y sí que tenemos, en cambio, *indefenso*.

Comment: @Gorpik Cierto. Y también *inconcluso* y seguramente algunos más de ese tipo. Creo que hemos descubierto una tendencia... 

Comment: Mencionaba *indefenso* porque en tu respuesta hablas de *defeso* y *defendido*, pero sí, parece que es habitual que los adjetivos negativos irregulares se mantengan, mientras que los positivos acaben asimilándose al participio regular del verbo correspondiente.